# Rails 3.1 link_to weird issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am having hands on Rails 3.1 rc1. There is a weird issue keeps bothering me. Whenever I use `link_to` function, the link `href` also appearing.

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Say Hello' , '/say/hello' %>
```

produces the below output in the browser

```
Say Hello (`/say/hello`)
```

I don't know why the link `href` also displaying this way.

I tried the below as well:

```
< a href="/say/hello"> Say Hello < /a>
```

Still the same output. It seems like the issue is not related to Rails ???

Please help. You advise is valuable.

Comment: You're most likely overwriting the link_to helper somewhere in your own code.

Comment: Hi, The problem here is the html code looks good, but when i see it in the browser it is showing the href link as well inside the brackets. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: It's happening because <insert my first comment here, again>

Comment: @fx_, this has nothing to do with `link_to`, as it happens when he uses raw HTML too. It's definitely a CSS issue as the answer points out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using blueprint?  I was seeing the same issue, and it was due to blueprint's `print.css`:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

Comment: yep, you are correct, i removed it and it worked. Thanks for replying.